# Cassandra order by second clustering key

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I have a table in cassandra and I want to order by the second clustering column and leave the first clustering column. It is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
key int,
value1 text,
value2 text,
value3 text,
comments text,
PRIMARY KEY (key, value1, value2, value3)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value2 DESC);
```

I know that the above script is wrong and I should change it below:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
key int,
value1 text,
value2 text,
value3 text,
comments text,
PRIMARY KEY (key, value1, value2, value3)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value1 DESC, value2 DESC);
```

but I want to sort it by the only value2(and not the value1). Is it possible? Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible out of box - data is sorted hierarchically inside the partition - first they are sorted by first clustering column, then sorted inside every unique value of "parent column", etc. Something like this (CL - clustering column):

```
partition key:
  CL1 value 1:
    CL2 value 1
    CL2 value 2
  CL1 value 2
    CL2 value 1
    CL2 value 3
  ...
```