# Sorting Cassandra Query Output Data

Tags: sorting, cassandra, output, primary-key

I am sure this is the most common problem with Cassandra.
Nevertheless:

I have this example table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test1 (
a text,
b text,
c timestamp,
id uuid,
d timestamp,
e decimal,
PRIMARY KEY ((a),c, b, id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (b ASC, compartment ASC);
```

My query:

```
select b, (toUnixTimestamp(d) - toUnixTimestamp(c))/1000/60/60/24/365.25 as age from test.test1  where a = 'x' and c > -2208981600000 ;
```

This works fine but I can't get the data sorted by column b which I need.  I need all the entries in column b and their corresponding 'age's.

eg:

```
select b, (toUnixTimestamp(d) - toUnixTimestamp(c))/1000/60/60/24/365.25 as age from test.test1  where a = 'x' and c > -2208981600000 order by b;
```

gives the error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by currently only supports the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY"
```

I have tried different orders in the clustering columns and different options in the partition key but I get caught by some logic and just can't seem to outwit Cassandra to get what I want. If I get the sort order I want, I loose the ability to filter on column 'c'.

Is there some logic I am not applying here, or alternatively, what must I omit(?) to get a list of entries in column b with the corresponding age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - it's impossible to sort data on arbitrary column using CQL, even if it's a part of the primary key.  Cassandra sorts data first by first clustering column, then inside it by second, etc. (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624304/cassandra-order-by-second-clustering-key/64625082#64625082)).

So the only workaround right now is to fetch all data & sort on the client side.

Comment: Thank you @alex-ott. Stick to the set rules is the answer. As I understand more I will be able to do more.

Comment: I recommend to grab this free book: https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide

Comment: Thank you for the link.